# Get exact SMART error from Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology)

Tags: raid, ssd, intel, nvme

On one system I use dual NVMe m.2 drives on an Intel Z170 board in RAID0 with Intel RST.

After about 6 months of light use the Intel RST Tool gives me a SMART error. [image: See error here]

The only option I have is to suppress the error. Instead of suppressing I would like to know what SMART error it is. I am looking for detailed SMART reports such as Temperature, Reallocated Sector count and Raw_Read_error_Rate etc.
There seems to be no such information in the Intel RST tool besides the information that there is a SMART problem.
All 3rd party tools I have tried can not read SMART behind the Intel RST RAID or do not support NVMe at all.

What can I do to get the cause and datail info about the SMART error on this SSD?

Comment: Out of interest what are you using a Z170-based system for here? Secondly if they're less than 12 months old then they'll be in warranty won't they? get the dead one swapped.

Comment: There is 2 years of waranty that the device was ok at time of purchase by law in Europe. I still want a tool that can tell me the SMART status through the softraid. I mean the Intel RST tool shows me that there is an error, just not which.

Comment: Good news, either way see @mzhasse's post below, their drivers are worth keeping on top of too btw, some big performance benefits to be had - big fan of the P3608 here :)

Comment: I am sorry, but the suggestion in @mzhaase's post does not work. The tool is useless. It does not show any SMART status at all for the SSD drives.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Crystal Disk Info**. I find it adequate:

[image]

Comment: No, it does not work. It only shows my USB HDD. I am using latest "[2016/10/10] CrystalDiskInfo 7.0.4", and "Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) RAID Driver
Version: 15.2.0.1020 (Latest) Date: 10/20/2016". Are you sure it works with NVMe?

Comment: They say on the front page - version you mention has official support for nvme on windows 10, if windows 8.1 or earlier you need to install Intel/samsung nvme driver. Can't say anything more for it since I'm not involved in this project (and I don't have NVMe).

Comment: Thanks, it is running on Windows 10. Contacted the CrystalDiskInfo author via email on 19th of Dec, no reply so far.

Comment: CrystalDiskInfo  7.0.5 [2017/01/01] released today has "Fixed NVMe S.M.A.R.T. issues" in changelog but it still *does not work*. I am giving up on CrystalDiskInfo for now. Any other idea how to read the smart status?

Answer (score 2):

Boot a linux live cd and use `smartctl` from the smartmontools package to read the SMART status of the drive.  Or if you have a bootable Windows disk and prefer to use that, change the RAID mode back to AHCI in your bios, boot from the other disk, then your normal tools should see the individual drives and read the SMART health.  Switch back to RAID mode in the bios to boot normally.

Answer (score 1):

The Intel SSD Toolbox should do that:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18455

Comment: The Intel SSD Toolbox sees the RAID as one drive and not the individual SSD drives. It claims SMART is disabled. It does not work. It is like the other 3rd party tools I have tried, that can not read SMART behind the Intel RST raid or do not support NVMe. If you have one that works please let me know! Or an Intel commandline tool or something.

Comment: You got the bounty even though your answer is not a solution. Maybe you can still come up with a solution?